Cannot find module '@utils/prisma' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
If you're facing a similar problem in your Next.js project where TypeScript is unable to find the module @utils/prisma or its corresponding type declarations, there's a solution that you can try. Open your Visual Studio Code terminal and run the following command: npx prisma db push

there's a solution that you can try. Open your Visual Studio Code terminal and run the following command: npx prisma db push
